# SQL, check on specific date

Tags: sql, date, datetime

I wanna get all records where "F.EINDAT" is smaller or even as **yesterday 8pm**.

`WHERE F.EINDAT <= yesterday at 8pm`

How am I supposed to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: In most cases it should work if you'll enter your date at ISO format, e.g. '2014-11-06 20:00:00'.

Comment: WHERE F.EINDAT <= DATEADD(hour, 20, CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 112)))

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select  substring(convert(varchar,(getdate()-1)),1,12)+'20:00:00 PM'  as Early_Date
```

Comment: select getdate() -->07-Nov-14 12:55:10 PM

Comment: 24 hour format does not have AM or PM specification.

Comment: 07-Nov-14 12:55:10 PM  -->Toad....2014-11-07 13:00:44.337--->ssms      so can take it without the PM.                                    select  substring(convert(varchar,(getdate()-1)),1,12)+'20:00:00'

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
WHERE F.EINDAT <= CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE()), 110)  + ' 20:00'
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope you will find this helpful

```
F.EINDAT <= cast(DateAdd(day, -1, GetDate()) as date) and
RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DATEPART(HOUR, F.EINDAT)), 2) + ':00' <= '20:00'
```

Answer (score 0):

select * from *tablename*
where *timestampcolumn* > cast(current_date as timestamp) - interval'4'hour;

ISO/ANSI SQL compliant.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all answers.

I got a statement which works for me:

```
where f.eindat >= to_date((to_Char (SYSDATE-1, 'yyyy-mm-dd') || ' 20:00'),'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi')
```